# Getting two email notifications for the same post matching my filter

Tags: bug, notifications, email, subscription

I have one filter on Stack Overflow that matches "javamail".
Lately I've been getting two email notifications for the same
post that matches the filter.  This doesn't happen every time,
but maybe one out of five matching posts.  The two notifications
come about an hour and a half apart.

Looking at a diff of the MIME content of the notification messages,
I see that the unsubscribe links are different.  Other than that,
the differences are pretty much as expected.

I can imagine a lot of reasons the email notification process might
accidentally send the same notification twice, e.g., if there's a
failure somewhere in the notification process, but this is happening
more frequently lately.

Is this a known problem?

Here's a diff of the unsubscribe links:

```
<                     <a href="https://stackexchange.com/email/unsubscribe-filte
r/58759/1422199398?code=VbMzA92sJ%2fW1NI9oKeWclvNoZcdGo3P%2bVo89Ncfg63o%3d" styl
e="color: #0077cc; text-decoration: none;">Unsubscribe from this filter</a> or c
hange your email preferences by visiting
---
>                     <a href="https://stackexchange.com/email/unsubscribe-filte
r/58759/1105383855?code=AcKw%2bj%2bvIv%2fXtvLeCy2SEfLTHvd27ISMLnUKtSAivFs%3d" st
yle="color: #0077cc; text-decoration: none;">Unsubscribe from this filter</a> or
 change your email preferences by visiting
351c351
```

Comment: Did you go through account merge lately?

Comment: Can you include the two unsubscribe links, or at least a diff of them?  That would help us figure out if it's coming from two different subscriptions, two different accounts (like a merge), or something else.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what "account merge" is.  I do have accounts on multiple stack exchange sites, and I do think I "merged" them a few weeks ago.  Is that somehow related to this problem?  I do **not** have multiple stackoverflow accounts.

Comment: I updated my post with a diff of the unsubscribe links.

Comment: @BillShannon I see. Well, I'm afraid only a developer can shed more light on this. In the meanwhile, try to delete the filter and re-create in order to avoid the double notifications. Also, when replying in comments, better ping so the other user will be notified, I saw your comment here by chance. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry, I thought the default was to notify anyone who participated in a post of any updates to the post so there was no need to mention you explicitly.

Comment: @Bill nope, the reasoning is less noise to those who don't need/want it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard And people who do need it missing important updates.  Sigh.  Ok, I understand how it works now.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I now understand that I have to mention you to make sure you're notified of my comments above.

Comment: @BillShannon yes. Agree it has downsides, but repeated requests to change this were rejected both by the users (lots of downvotes) and SE itself.

Comment: The same thing has been happening to me - it started happening several weeks ago, on email filters that I have had in place for many months/years. Across all sites I have email-filters set: Webmasters, WordPress and ServerFault. I would say "most" of the time I am getting a double email. If the question has been edited then I'm getting the edited question in the second email (although I am getting double emails when there have been no edits). I have tried removing and recreating the email filters, but this doesn't appear to have made any difference. I have not "merged" any accounts.

Comment: I also tried removing and recreating my filter but that didn't solve the problem.  How can I be sure that someone at StackExchange is aware of this bug?  I'm not demanding an immediate fix, I just want to make sure this is known and not forgotten.